# How to directly embed object from memory into a RichTextItem

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

In my XPages application, I work with BufferedImages (java.awt.image). Up to now, when I want to embed them in a NotesDocument, I first have to save the BufferedImages to disk and afterwards attach the corresponding image files to a NotesRichTextItem:

```
NotesRichTextItem.embedObject(NotesEmbeddedObject.EMBED_ATTACHMENT,"","C:\path\to\BufferedImage.png",null).
```

Is there a way to avoid saving the BufferedImages to disk and instead directly embed them as objects in the NotesRichTextItem? For example by converting them into a byte array, creating a new NotesEmbeddedObject from that array and adding that NotesEmbeddedObject to the NotesRichTextItem...

PS: I'm not searching for a workaround using MIME entity attachments because all the routines in my application expect the files to be embedded in certain NotesRichTextItems.

Answer (score 2):

You can embedd them into the richtext field as mime entities.
Check out these two xSnippet and how it does this for HTML emails.

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=create-html-mails-in-ssjs-using-mime

http://openntf.org/XSnippets.nsf/snippet.xsp?id=emailbean-send-dominodocument-html-emails-cw-embedded-images-attachments-custom-headerfooter

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this kind of approach, but (as I stated in my question) I do not want to use this workaround. Processing NotesMIMEEntities is somewhat different from processing NotesRichTextItems and I would have to rewrite a lot of routines in my application.

Answer (score 1):

The LotusScript Gold Collection on openntf.org contains code showing how to manipulate attachments in memory via DXL. This does mean that you can't write the attachment into the document except via the final import. Look at the AttachmentAdder script library. FileResource library may also be of interest.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have not been working with DXL before, but if there is no "simpler" way to achieve what I want, I'll have to give it a try. I'll test your solution first before marking your answer as accepted.